# How to make mat-select always open right under the form field in angular2?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular-material2

I need the angular material mat-select component to open right under it's form field but it opens the dropdown on selected option position and the container moves a little to top according to the selected option.
Is there a way to open the drop-down container right under the form field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior is prescribed by Material Design. You can turn off the centering over the selected option with the `disableOptionCentering` option, but this puts the top option over the field not below it. You could override that using CSS by specifying a `panelClass` option and set `display` and `position` properties appropriately, but this will not work properly if the window space prevents the panel from opening in the standard position.