# How to always keep mat-menu at the same position?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have this custom dropdown and I'm using mat-checkbox for the items to be selected. Anyway, my issue is that when I open the mat-menu and then I select items (let's select 2 items) at this time  my **mat-menu** is at a specific position. Now if I close the mat-menu and open it again you'll see that the mat-menu is at a higher position (it moves like 5px up or so). Does anyone know how to always keep the mat-menu at the same position even after selecting items? Thanks a lot in advance.

**NOTE:** I tried using disableOptionCentering but it doesn't work on mat-menu only on mat-select

Here my [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq35bw-kuz4vd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html)

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="menu-select">
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="chipList">
        </ng-container>
        <div *ngFor="let topping of toppingList">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="listOfItems && listOfItems.indexOf(topping)>=0"
                (change)="change(topping,$event.checked)">
                {{topping}}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging your code in stackblitz shows that you change the chip list in each selecting, leading to the recalculation of the dropdown panel height and position.
So the problem is more of a XY problem.
The code needs some refactoring of the array where you keep values. And use a pipe instead of a method that will be run on each click and reorder the ngFor.
So here is my approach.

Typescript:

```
...
  toppingList = [
    { item: "item 1", selected: false },
    { item: "testing abc", selected: false },
    { item: "item 3", selected: false },
    { item: "Pepperoni", selected: false },
    { item: "Sausage", selected: false },
    { item: "Tomato", selected: false }
  ];
...



import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
  name: "myFilter",
  pure: false
})
export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(myArray: any[]) {
    return myArray.filter(item => item.selected);
  }


}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="menu-select">
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="chipList">
        </ng-container>
        <div *ngFor="let topping of toppingList">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="topping.selected"
                (change)="topping.selected=!topping.selected">
                {{topping.item}}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
<ng-template #chipList>
    <mat-chip-list aria-label="Fruit selection">
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of (toppingList|myFilter)" removable="true">
            {{fruit.item}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove (click)="fruit.selected=false">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
</ng-template>
```

In this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq35bw-sybuj9?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.html) you can see that the menu always stays at the same position without any styling needed. Your code will be much lighter and readable

Comment: @Double-expesso I see that your answer works but it's missing something that y code had. Let's say you select 2 items, then click outside the mat-menu then I want to should the container that has only the selected items (my previous code does that). How could you implement that with your solution? Thank you

Comment: Check the demo again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're doing a custom multiple select using the mat-menu component on purpose, but it isn't its intended use.

I'd recommend using the mat-select component with the [`multiple` property](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection). It easier to maintain and will also look much neater

Although you use the chips being displayed within the dropdown itself, I think that's not an issue, they shouldn't be inside the dropdown, it's not its purpose and makes it confusing from a UI/UX perspective.

I made a [Stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rq35bw-bkawhx?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.html) to illustrate.

Now the dropdown still gets displayed on top of the input (default behavior) to change that, have a look at the `paneClass` property. [Here's a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360584/how-to-make-mat-select-always-open-right-under-the-form-field-in-angular2)

Comment: I want to display the chips as I select an item (check an item) just like I have it in my code (demo), but your solution doesn't do that.

Comment: Again, displaying the chips WITHIN the dropdown seem a bit unnecessary and more confusing than not (especially since select checkboxes will move down when chips are getting added). Chips and checkboxes have similar functionality here too. Maybe displaying chips on the input field, or next to it would be a nice alternative.
But if that layout is a requirement then mat- might require a few tweaks to make it work